# NullPointerException when trying to access ArrayList from other class

Tags: java, oop

I'm writing a program that manages inventory, like through adding, removing, and renting items, all by using multiple classes in an object-oriented atmosphere. Below is my implementation class (Driver).

**Driver.java**

```
public class Driver {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      ABCRentals abc = new ABCRentals();
      Furniture item1 = new Furniture();
      boolean flag = abc.add(item1);
      List<Integer> idList = abc.getIDList();
      String[] itemTypes = abc.getItemArray();
      System.out.println("Item ID Numbers: " + Arrays.toString(idList.toArray()));
      System.out.println("Item Types: " + Arrays.toString(itemTypes));
   }
}
```

This code works just fine, as it is able to retrieve and print the ArrayList and String array through the `getIDList()` and `getItemArray()` methods, which are specified here in the `ABCRentals` class:

**ABCRentals.java**

```
public class ABCRentals implements Inventory
{
   private List<Integer> idNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
   private List<Integer> rentedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   private String[] itemTypes2;

   public ABCRentals() { }

   public List<Integer> getIDList() {
      return idNumbers;
   }

   public List<Item> getItemList() {
      return items; 
   }

   public String[] getItemArray() {
      return itemTypes2;
   }

   public List<Integer> getRentedList() {
      return rentedItems;
   }

   public boolean add(Item item)
   {
      if (items.size() >= 300)
          return false;
      else
      {
         idNumbers.add(idNumbers.size() + 1);
         items.add(item);
         Object[] itemTypes = items.toArray();
         itemTypes2 = new String[itemTypes.length];
         int dvd = 0, f = 0, tv = 0;
         for (int index = 0; index < itemTypes.length; index++)
         {
            String indexValue = itemTypes[index].getClass().toString().substring(6);
            if (indexValue.equals("DVDPlayer"))
            {
              dvd++;
              itemTypes2[index] = indexValue + " #" + Integer.toString(dvd);
            }
            if (indexValue.equals("Furniture"))
            {
              f++;
              itemTypes2[index] = indexValue + " #" + Integer.toString(f);
            }
            if (indexValue.equals("Television"))
            {
              tv++;
              itemTypes2[index] = indexValue + " #" + Integer.toString(tv);
            }
          }
          return true;
      }
}
```

So when I try to access the ArrayList's and array's contents from the `Driver` class, it works. However, when I try to access the ArrayList or array from any other class, whether it's the `DVDPlayer`, `Furniture`, or `Television` class, I get a `NullPointerException` error, so in other words the ArrayList and array are not updated/populated with the values specified in the `Driver` class from the `add()` method and instead are returned as empty, unlike above. I'll use the `Furniture` class for example:

**Furniture.java**

```
public class Furniture implements Item
{
   private ABCRentals abc = new ABCRentals();
   public List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   public String[] itemArray = abc.getItemArray();
   private int ID;
   private static int idNumber = 0;

   public Furniture()
   {
      ID = ++idNumber;
   }

   public String getId()
   {
      int index = Arrays.asList(itemArray).indexOf("Furniture #" + Integer.toString(ID));
      id = Integer.toString(index);
      return id;
   }
}
```

And then adding this one line of code to the Driver class from above after the `String[] itemTypes = abc.getItemArray()` line results in the `NullPointerException`:

```
String id = item1.getId();
```

To make things simple, the `Driver` class can access the contents of the ArrayList and array stored in the `ABCRentals` class through the `getIDList()` and `getItemArray()` methods, but classes like `Furniture` cannot. The only difference seems to be one class has a `main()` method whereas the other doesn't. Am I not declaring `ABCRentals` objects in the `Furniture` class correctly to get updated values? **IMPORTANT:** I cannot change the `getId()` method to accept an argument like an ArrayList, because this is a homework assignment that requires to have the same classes and method signatures as specified. Sorry if this looks like a code dump, but I think it is important to understand every step I am trying to accomplish to understand my problem. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You never seem to initialize `public String[] itemArray`, so it will be `null` when you call `Arrays.asList(itemArray)`.

Comment: From the code you have shown I don't see you assign anything at all to `itemArray`. If you don't assign anything to it, it will remain `null` and therefore it will throw an NPE. You will need to assign a value _before_ you call `getId()`. (Or at least before the `Arrays.asList(itemArray)`.)

Comment: @Ivar this may be hard to believe, but I accidentally mis-copied that line of code into this question. I edited my question to the line `public String[] itemArray = abc.getItemArray();`

Comment: In that case `itemArray` still is `null`. You call `itemArray = abc.getItemArray()` where `abc` is a new instance. The `abc.add()` method is never called at the point you assign `getItemArray()` back to the `itemArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call your add() method in your main, which instantiates the itemTypes2 array.
You don't call add() before accessing itemTypes2 in your Furniture class, so it is null.